# What is the difference between the Text property and the inner text of an asp:Label tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

One can specify label text to be displayed in 2 different ways:

**Method 1:**

```asp
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
   Text="Enter search string (optional):" ></asp:Label>
```

This will display: `Enter search string (optional):` Label text can be set from your code using `Label1.Text = "SomeText";`

**Method 2:**

```asp
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
   Text="Enter search string (optional):" >Please enter search string</asp:Label>
```

In this case Text attribute is ignored and it will display: `Please enter search string`

In all of the samples I saw Method 1 is used.

When would someone use Method 2 (if ever)? How can label text be set from your code for Method 2?

Comment: @Alex: yes, but this would change Text attribute instead of content between opening and closing tags

Comment: they are the same. Content between opening and closing tags just overwrites Text attribute, so it changes both.

Comment: @JoeSchmoe: I think you really need to change the question title !!!

Comment: Keep in mind that a label control is really just a <span> tag when it hits the browser. <span> tags are typically used as a wrapper for text, and most often don't contain any other semantic meaning outside of grouping or styling. To keep with the ASP.NET conventions, using the controls "Text" attribute is probably the preferred way to go. By changing the "Text" property on the control, anything inside the rendered <span> tag is wiped out anyways, so it is unlikely that you would be nesting other elements inside of a label control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` property directly assigns `Label1.Text`. Writing in the tag's "inner text" adds a `LiteralControl` to the label's `Controls` collection.

The difference is that you could nest multiple controls in the label which can't be done through the `Text` property.

For example:

```asp
<asp:Label runat="server">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="/image.jpg" />Some text
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that by nesting controls like this, if the labels text property is ever changed the internal content is completely wiped out.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use Label1.innerText property to get the inner text of your control

Comment: There is no `innerText` on the server side.